# jquery onclick returns all values and undefined in a loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to returning the clicked element's "data-id" attribute value with jquery but this code is returning all id from the loop not only the clicked element's id

```
<?php
$datas = get_users_data(); // this is returning an array from MySQL like user's id, username etc...
foreach ($datas as $data) {
    $id = $data["id"];
?>

    <td><a href="#" id="edit" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="edit">Edit</a></td>

    <?php } ?>

    <script>
    $(document).on('click', '.edit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).attr("data-id"));
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: An `id` should be unique, `id="edit"` is not unique. You could do `. edit` on click and then use `$(this)` to target it

Comment: You are right, I edited the code. now it's almost working... but still getting undefined too. First it's returns the id and then changing to undefined.

Comment: Can you please add the full message? JS or PHP undefined error?

Comment: What do you mean? It's showing an alert with the ID first correctly then I clicking on the OK button and showing an undefined alert too.

Comment: Please include a *complete* snippet - ideally of *rendered* code - the php doesn't help as it will depend on get_users_data().   The code you've provided will only give one alert per click, so if you are getting 2 alerts on a single click ("*but getting undefined too*" could mean on a single click or clicking a 2nd row) then it might be because you have nested .edit classes.   If we can *see* the error, I'm sure you'll get a quick fix.

Comment: Oh well, I changed the class "edit" to "edit2" (of course in the jquery too) and now works well... maybe there is already have an edit class somewhere in the code. But thanks for your help guys.